# Error 3097 : The VPSProtocol value is outside the valid range. Should be between 2.00 and 3.00

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, opayo

I have upgraded Sagapay plugin in woocommerce wordpress site for PSD2 regulation and when trying to place an order gets this error : The transaction registration could not be completed, due to a missing parameter or an invalid parameter. Details: 3097 : The VPSProtocol value is outside the valid range. Should be between 2.00 and 3.00.

Is there any setting change or verification I need to check in my sagapay account settings and something is wrong with the plugin itself.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Ritaja

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a bug in a plugin (a software), and should be solved with the plugin authors in their support threads.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the SagePay live server. 3DSv2, requiring protocol 4.0, is not live yet. You need to use the Test Server in order to test your new code.

Verify that you are connecting to the Test Server. If still a problem it could be a SagePay issue as they still work on that as far as I know..

Comment: do you know when v4 will be available on production?

Comment: @Pencho Ilchev SagePay hasn't mentioned anything about that so far. I did post some more about that on SO to the question When will Protocol v4.0 be enabled on the Live servers? You should find it easily.